# Updating window dimensions on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, document, document-body

So I was looking through SO and found this:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

function t(){
    test.innerHTML = "x = "+x+"\ny = "+y;
}

window.onload = t;
window.onresize = t;
```

with a [Fiddle Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L6uPV/show/4), and i was wondering if there's a way to make the values automatically refresh when i resize my window without manually pressing F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the `t` function on resize, but you're not updating the `x` and `y` values in there. They are only set on load, hence the problem. Change you logic so they are amended within the function. Try this:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x, y;

function t() {
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
    test.innerHTML = "x = " + x + "\ny = " + y;
}

window.onload = t;
window.onresize = t;
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L6uPV/287/)

With that said, if you need to know the size of the window to update the UI in certain conditions, then you should really be using CSS media queries, not JS.

Comment: May I ask you another quick related question? What's the difference between `window.width` and `window.innerWidth`? I've noticed with the former i can't do operations like `*0.9` to resize it a bit while with the latter i can.

Comment: There is no `window.width` property so I'm not sure where you're getting that from. It's possible some browsers implement it, but it's certainly not part of the standard. I'd suggest you always use `innerWidth`

Comment: It's not in the question, but I am actually using it in my project and works fine, just can't do operations on it

Answer (score 2):

You should call the function on resize also,

```
var onresize = function() {
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
    test.innerHTML = "x = "+x+"\ny = "+y;
}
window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!